# Cosa significa "alcinesco" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro *Danubio*, di Claudio Magris, ho letto:

> L'isola di Brăila, lunga 60 chilometri e compresa fra il braccio principale del Danubio e il Danubio vecchio, è un Eden liquido e **alcinesco**, in cui regna il giunco e presso il quale i goti, come ricorda Gibbon, accettarono di consegnare ai romani le loro donne e i loro figli, ma non le loro armi.

Non capisco il significato di "alcinesco" in questo brano: non ho trovato questo aggettivo in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino che abbia a che vedere con l'Alcina dell'*Orlando Furioso*, ma non riesco a cogliere il senso di questa parola. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Affascinate, attraente... questo è il significato.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @massimo! Qui ci aspettiamo una risposta più approfondita e argomentata. Per questa ragione il tuo post è stato convertito in un commento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per quello che ne riesco a capire, si tratta infatti di un riferimento all'Alcina dell'*Orlando Furioso*, una fata risiedente in un isola incantata che seduceva e poi trasformava in piante tutti coloro che vi si recavano.

In questo caso credo che *alcinesco* sia usato come sinonimo di *fatato* (o forse *ammaliante*), a maggior ragione perché si riferisce ad un isola.

Comment: Non dimenticherei l'opera “L'isola di Alcina” di Joseph Haydn.

Comment: @egreg Onestamente, io sono più familiare con quella di Händel (dove la magia di Alcina è una non troppo velata metafora per la musica e l'opera stessa), ma a ciascuno i suoi gusti. Ci sono più opere basate sull'Orlando furioso che su qualsiasi altro pezzo di letteratura, credo...

Comment: Se la fata trasformava le persone in piante, è possibile che l'aggettivo  indichi anche una vegetazione lussureggiante.